# Difference between two density plots

Tags: r, plot

Is there a simple way to plot the difference between two probability density functions?

I can plot the pdfs of my data sets (both are one-dimensional vectors with roughly 11000 values) on the same plot together to get an idea of the overlap/difference but it would be more useful to me if I could see a plot of the difference.

something along the lines of the following (though this obviously doesn't work):

```
> plot(density(data1)-density(data2))
```

I'm relatively new to R and have been unable to find what I'm looking for on any of the forums.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should work:

```
plot(x =density(data1, from= range(c(data1, data2))[1], 
                       to=range(c(data1, data2))[2] )$x, 
  y=  density(data1, from= range(c(data1, data2))[1], 
                     to=range(c(data1, data2))[2] )$y-
       density(data2,  from= range(c(data1, data2))[1], 
                      to=range(c(data1, data2))[2] )$y )
```

The trick is to make sure the densities have the same limits. Then you can plot their differences at the same locations.My understanding of the need for the identical limits comes from having made the error of not taking that step in answering a [similar question on Rhelp several years ago](http://finzi.psych.upenn.edu/Rhelp10/2008-January/152469.html). Too bad I couldn't remember the right arguments.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you need to spend a little time learning how to use R (or any other language, for that matter).  Help files are your friend.
From  the output of `?density` :

> Value  [i.e. the data returned by the function]
>
> If give.Rkern is true, the number R(K), otherwise an object with class
>   "density" whose underlying structure is a list containing the
>   following components.
>
> x  the n coordinates of the points where the density is estimated.
>
> y  the estimated density values. These will be non-negative, but can
>   be zero [remainder of "value" deleted for brevity]

So,  do:

```
foo<- density(data1) 
bar<- density(data2)
plot(foo$y-bar$y)
```

Comment: @Joran - thanks for cleaning up.  And DWin makes a good point: by default, `density` uses 512 points, but if you muck with the grid OR the ranges of data1 and data2 are different, you'll want to make sure foo$x and bar$x are "aligned" .

Comment: I edited your answer (very) slightly to help you avoid being flagged. I get frustrated with beginners too, but that acronym can rub people the wrong way, and is generally frowned upon here.

Comment: Thanks for the insight. I had read ?density, but I guess I wasn't familiar enough with R syntax to make proper use of what it was telling me. All part of the learning process!